# Modelo glmer de poisson

Tags: r, glm, glmer

Estou no R fazendo um glmer GLMM de Poisson em que tenho a variável resposta que é a riqueza de espécies e as variáveis preditoras em que foram transformadas em dummies por serem categóricas. No caso tenho o seguinte código,

```
modelo_dados_dummies <- glmer(riqueza ~ ecorregiao + metodo + tipo + manejo + cultivo + 
                              (1 | artigo), 
                              data = dados, family = poisson)
```

as categorias dummies mais frequentes estão no intercepto. Estou tentando rodar o dredge, library(MuMIn), options(na.action = "na.fail") desta forma: dredge(modelo_dados_dummies,rank = "AICc"). Mas está demorando muitas horas e não sai o resultado. Meu interesse é a busca pelos melhores modelos com delta AIC menor ou igual a 2. Por gentileza uma ajuda, sabem dizer se tem como configurar para que a busca seja mais rápida. Porque contando são 25 dummies preditoras.

Comment: Olá Ezequiel, bem vindo ao SOpt. Sem saber como são seus dados e sem avaliar a performance do modelo, sua pergunta não tem como ser respondida adequadamente. No máximo, usuários podem passar dicas gerais baseadas em suposições, o que sai do propósito do SO.